# sql statement to update a real column with values from a ranked virtual column

Tags: java, sql

i have a table that selects values from a total column and ranks the result into a computed column, but because the computed column is not a real column, i want to copy the same values from the computed column into a real column in the same table.

```
private void classStatistics(){
    try{

     String sql ="select s1.Name as 'Pupil',s1.Maths_Total as 'Total Score',"
     + "s1.Maths_G as 'Grade',s1.Maths_R as 'Remark',s1.maths_Pos AS 
     'Position',COUNT(DISTINCT s2.maths_Total) AS Rank from class1 s1 JOIN 
     class1 s2 on(s1.maths_Total<=s2.maths_Total)GROUP BY s1.ID order by s1.Name 
     ASC ";  

    pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    rs=pst.executeQuery();
    class1_statistics.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));



    }
    catch(Exception e){
    e.getMessage();
    }
    finally{
    try{
    rs.close();
    pst.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
      }
    }
    class1Entry();
    }
```

This creates the computed column as Rank and i want to update the a column named Position with the same values from the computed ranked column.
I wrote this code for that.

// and this for my update into my chosen column 'Maths_Pos'

```
private void getPosition(){
    try{
    String sql= "Update class1 set Maths_Pos=(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT 
 s2.maths_Total) AS Rank from class1 s1 JOIN class1 s2 
 on(s1.maths_Total<=s2.maths_Total)GROUP BY s1.ID order by s1.Name ASC )";
    pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    pst.execute();
    }catch(Exception e){  

    }
finally{
           try{
              rs.close();
              pst.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
            }
        }
    }
```

But what this does is to repeat just the first rank value of the first row for all the remaining rows. so instead of having different values in the column, have having the same value running across all rows in the column.

Comment: l don't follow your question.  Can you edit it and include sample data along with the raw SQL queries which you imagine are involved here?

Comment: Indent your code properly if you would like people to try and read it.

Answer (score 0):

In your update:

```
    String sql= "Update class1 set Maths_Pos=(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT 
 s2.maths_Total) AS Rank from class1 s1 JOIN class1 s2 
 on(s1.maths_Total<=s2.maths_Total)GROUP BY s1.ID order by s1.Name ASC )";
```

Your sub-select isn't correlated to your outer query.

You should alias class1 in the outer query and correlate on the grouping column(s):

```
    String sql= "Update c set Maths_Pos=(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT 
 s2.maths_Total) AS Rank from class1 s1 JOIN class1 s2 
 on s1.maths_Total<=s2.maths_Total WHERE s1.ID=c.ID GROUP BY s1.ID order by s1.Name ASC ) FROM class1 c ";
```

Comment: i get an sql exception that says: java.sql.SQLException: near "FROM": syntax error

Answer (score 0):

i am trying to create a rank column which will rank results from a 'Result Total Column'. i managed to create a virtual column which calculates the values in the 'Result Total Column' and displays the ranks in the 'Rank Column' with this code :

```
private void classStatistics(){
    try{

     String sql ="select s1.Name as 'Pupil',s1.Maths_Total as 'Total Score',"
            + "s1.Maths_G as 'Grade',s1.Maths_R as 'Remark',s1.maths_Pos AS 'Position',COUNT(DISTINCT s2.maths_Total) AS Rank from class1 s1 JOIN class1 s2 on(s1.maths_Total<=s2.maths_Total)GROUP BY s1.ID order by s1.Name ASC ";  

    pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    rs=pst.executeQuery();
    class1_statistics.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));



    }
    catch(Exception e){
    e.getMessage();
    }
    finally{
    try{
    rs.close();
    pst.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
      }
    }
    class1Entry();
    }
```

this displays the table below:

```html
<table border="1" style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Pupil</th>
     <th>Total Score</th> 
    <th>Grade</th>
    <th>Remark</th>
     <th>Position</th> 
    <th>Rank</th>
   </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
     <td>73%</td> 
    <td>B</td>
    <td>Very Good</td>
     <td></td> 
    <td>2</td>
   </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>Mary</td>
     <td>90%</td> 
    <td>A</td>
    <td>Excellent</td>
     <td></td> 
    <td>1</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>James</td>
     <td>50%</td> 
    <td>D</td>
    <td>Average</td>
     <td></td> 
    <td>3</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

what i want to do is to update 'Position Column' with the  results in the computed column 'Rank'